# Как правильно оформить прелоадер на сайте (react + redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть loading, который сообщает, пришли данные или нет. Дело в том, что данные могут прийти за считанные доли, соответственно лоадер пропадает очень быстро. Как сделать плавную загрузку данных? То есть, к примеру, после загрузки данных грузить прелоадер еще 1 секунду. Сделал через стейты, а именно:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   contentReady: false
  }
}

getProducts() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      contentReady: true
    }))
  }, 1000)
}

render() {
  const { list, loading, error } = this.props

  if (list.length > 0) {
    this.getProducts()
  }

if (error) {
  return (
    <div>Something went wrong while fetching products. Please, try again later.</div>
  )
}

if (this.state.contentReady) {
  return (
   <div>Данные</div>    
  )
}

return (
  <Preloader/>
)
```

Но постоянно выдается следующая ошибка: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Что нужно изменить? И хорошая ли практика делать именно так?

Comment: setTimeout не убит на unmount. Насчёт хорошо ли это,  варнинг сообщает, что нет. Изменить: убивать setTimeout на анмаунте

Comment: @bonusrk как правильно его убить? Я сделал так, но ошибка не пропадает:
clearTimeout(this.timerHandle), где this.timerHandle = моему setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не стоит делать `setState` внутри `render()`. Потому что вы можете попасть в условие `list.length > 0` несколько (или очень много) раз (при ререндере компоненты).

Воспользуйтесь `componentDidMount()` для загрузки данных:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('your_url')
         .then(response => {
              // тут вы получили данные и делаете таймаут
              this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                   this.setState({contentReady: true})
              }, 1000)
         })
}
```

Тогда есть 100% гарантия что не создастся много таймаутов.

И при размонтировании компоненты убивайте свой таймаут:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
}
```